# Modifying the source code of external libraries in Scala, IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a Spark project which uses HDFS. I need to edit some things in the source code of Spark, which is possible since it is open source.

However, I'm wondering on how to get all of this together and working. I downloaded the source-jar for Spark and attached it to my IntelliJ project, which by the way builds with Maven. This has given me the possibility to go from my code and for example use Ctrl+B to go and see the source code of `SparkContext`or any other code in the Spark library.

Anyhow, this code is locked and I cannot modify it. I have not found a way to unlock it. So after some searching on the internet it seems like the solution would be to find a way to build the whole Spark library as part of my project instead of using it as an external library.

How would I go by doing this? I am lost as to how to add it so the source code is part of the project, which package would it be a part of and so on? I have no idea where to start or how to do it at all.

Comment: You will either have to download the source code or extend the class and apply your functions by overriding.

Comment: Making changes to external libraries just for your project is almost never a good idea. It makes it really hard to maintain your code - what if a new version of the library comes out that you'd want to use? You'd have to redo your changes. Also, if the library works differently because of your changes, then it's going to be really hard for other developers to understand. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @Jesper this makes sense yeah. What if I do what @Ramesh Maharjan recommended. Simple example, I want to modify only one function in `SparkContext`, could I somehow extend the class and only write that one function and call my extension instead? How would I go about doing that? Although more specifically, my problem is something like this: a function in `SparkContext` has to be modified and some other functions in Spark and `HadoopInputFormat` which are called by that `SparkContext`function should be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off checking out the latest source code for Apache Spark, create a feature branch, put your changes there and then probably submit a merge request, so that it is officially available as part of the Apache packages.

If you do not want to do that, you could of course do it all by yourself, with just building the Spark package by yourself, having it somewhere in your company's internal repository so that you can pull it from there from your different environments.